# Odd Error in mariaDB Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mariadb

Hi i hope some one can help my problem is that when i try to add a foreign key constraint i get this error.

My database name is "hazard"

Child:

```
CREATE TABLE `child` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `a` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `b` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
```

Parent:

```
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `alfa` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `beta` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
```

Those are the create codes (using HeidiSQL)

and when i try to add a foreign key
with

```
ALTER TABLE CHILD MODIFY COLUMN A INT,add constraint fk_parent_child FOREIGN KEY(A) REFERENCES PARENT(ALFA);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE CHILD add constraint fk1 foreign key (a) references parent(alfa);
```

I get the same error

> Can't create table 'hazard.#sql-d04_53' (errno: 150)

this is happening to many of my classmates using MariaDB and mySQL

Beforehand an apology for the inconvenience and I hope you guys can help us.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error 150 usually means you are updating the tables in the wrong order.  That is, your *first* INSERT violates the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint that your `second` INSERT will fix.

In your case you are doing `ALTER` instead of `INSERT`.  Swap the order of the `ALTER`s.  If that does not work, check the data to see that you won't be violating FK constraints.  If you get past that, read on...

In extreme cases, you can turn off foreign key constraints while doing the inserts, then turn them back on.  (But that leaves you vulnerable to screw-ups.)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
KEY (`alfa`)
```

to the parent table. "The referenced columns must be a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index." – https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/foreign-keys/

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4c12